# Convert BDMV files to MKV format

Tags: media-converter, file-converter, ripping, mkv

I'd like to convert quite a few BDMV files to MKV files. I know you can do this with MakeMKV, which isn't freeware. Are there any good freeware programs out there to accomplish this?

Comment: Better! Next, please edit your question to tell use what OS you are using.

Comment: @user2230470 I don't have a BDMV file at hand right now but I believe Handbrake should do the job :)